# Can wind affect an F1 car's speed during qualifying and the race?

Tags: formula-1

F1 engineers really want their car designs to be more aerodynamic and wind-resistant. Some of the tracks in F1 can be cold, hot, or windy, depending on the season and time of day during the race. Can strong wind make a difference in terms of qualifying or during the race? For example, can the wind "push" the car from behind in order to get more speed and give an unintentional advantage?

Answer (score 2):

> Can strong wind make a difference in terms of qualifying or during the race?

Absolutely! The most dramatic examples of this come when you see a strong gust of wind unsettling a car sufficiently to cause a spin or other loss of control - during qualifying for the Hungarian GP in 2021 Carlos Sainz [crashed](https://the-race.com/formula-1/sainz-explains-how-35-40kph-tailwind-caused-q2-crash/) following a strong gust. But there effects that are less visible but still significant.

> For example, can the wind "push" the car from behind in order to get more speed and give an unintentional advantage?

A strong wind from behind (called a "tailwind") will definitely help increase straight-line speed, not so much because it's "pushing" the car exactly but rather that it's effectively reducing the aerodynamic drag on the car. The flipside of this comes when you arrive at the braking zone and entry to the corner at the end of the straight - much of an F1 cars grip comes from aerodynamic downforce generated by the car moving through the air, and in simplistic terms downforce is produced at the square of the speed. i.e. twice the speed equals four times the downforce. But as this is a purely aerodynamic effect it’s **not** about the car’s road speed, it’s really about the car speed relative to the *airspeed* - so a strong tailwind means less downforce, less downforce means less grip so you have to brake earlier and carry less speed into the corner.

Conversely a strong wind coming from in front of the car (a "headwind") will slow the car down in a straight line as it will increase the drag (like how it's harder trying to walk into a strong wind) but since the airspeed relative to the car is now *higher* you'll get higher levels of downforce and therefore you can brake later and carry more speed into the corner. The increased drag from a headwind also has an effect when you're talking about cars racing each other - the slipstream effect and DRS are both more powerful in a headwind (and the reverse into a tail wind).

How big an effect this all has varies from track to track - some, like Silverstone in the UK are geographically quite exposed and therefore strong (and often quite changeable) winds are common, but if we're talking pure lap time then it's unlikely to be large, and if the winds are reasonably consistent then it's going to be the same for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

Tailwinds (blowing in the direction of travel) and headwinds (blowing against the direction of travel) are [well-known phenomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headwind_and_tailwind), and they affect Formula One as well. A tailwind would increase the car's acceleration and top speed, and lower its fuel consumption; a headwind would have the opposite effect but would also allow the driver to brake later going into a corner.

I don't know how powerful these effects actually are in Formula One. To my knowledge, F1 cars are optimised to work as well as possible in any given wind condition, without relying on headwinds or tailwinds to improve performance.

It's also worth noting that crosswinds - winds that strike the car from the side - are considered unfavourable, as they can unbalance the car during cornering and potentially cause it to spin. The "shark fin" designs of the late 2000s and early 2010s were especially susceptible to this.